# How can I check if a page has been visited? (I'm using an array field on the user model and I'm trying to add the page id in it)

Tags: python, django

This is not really a problem, this is more of a question because I don't know how to do this thing.

So I need to check if a lesson has been done (by checking if the page has been visited once on a logged account).

I've been trying to check if the page has been visited. If not, the ID should be added in the array of visited pages. The if condition looked like this:

```
if lectie_id in Profile.lectiiRezolvate:
        pass
```

and I'm getting

```
argument of type 'DeferredAttribute' is not iterable
```

.

models.py from accounts

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lectiiRezolvate = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True)
    exercitiiRezolvate = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True)
    exercitiiProvocari = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Lectie
from accounts.models import Profile

def lectii(req):
    lectii = Lectie.objects.all().order_by("id")
    context = {
        'lectii': lectii
    }
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/lectii-selector.html', context)

def lectie(req, lectie_id):
    if lectie_id in Profile.lectiiRezolvate:
        pass
    lectie2 = get_object_or_404(Lectie, pk=lectie_id)
    lectiePDF = 'lectii/lectia-{}.pdf'.format(lectie2)
    context = {
        'lectiePDF': lectiePDF,
        'lectie2': lectie2
    }
    return render(req, '../templates/pagini/lectii.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Lectie(models.Model):
    YTLink = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    capitol = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    cardText = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

So how can I store for each user the lessons he has accessed at least once? I suppose I have to loop into the array of solved lessons to check for the id for the actual lesson. If it's not there, I have to add it. If it is, do nothing.

But as you can see, when i'm trying to do this, I get an error.

Comment: Instead of an ArrayField use a ManyToMany relation between Lectures and Profiles (or better Users).

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code samples you pasted. I'd recommend narrowing this down to what exactly bothers you. And what throws the error. If we're looking at the first code sample, I can tell you that's now how you do field lookups. Probably something like `request.user.profile.filter(lectiiRezolvate__contains='someID').exists()` would get you on a better path.

Comment: @KlausD. can you get into more details? I'm a beginner and I'm not sure what you're talking about. I feel like this wouldn't be a good idea if MTM relations work as I think they do.

Comment: @Alex Can you help me sort out the issues? Is it sufficient if I use your code for my app to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check manually each object:

```
found = False
for profile in Profile.objects.all():
    if lectie_id in profile.lectiiRezolvate:
        found = True
        # logic here
```